# Multiple buttons but one text input HTML with PHP

Tags: html, forms, input

Let's say you have a little form in HTML with a text input and a submit button, just like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Text to encode/decode: <input type="text" name="textoencode"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

How would I add another button and *index.php* would know what button I pressed?

Also, I'm trying to make the PHP code execute some Python code that I have in another file, but I know how to do that already.

I would like my PHP code to know what button was pressed, if encode was pressed, run some code, and if decode was pressed, run some other code.

Comment: Give the buttons values, then check the passed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add one *if* in PHP and simply pass the name in the form when the button is clicked. And then the code inside the *if condition* executed.

**PHP code**:

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['phpbutton'])) {
        // Your code that you want to execute
    }
?>
```

**HTML**:

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Text to encode/decode: <input type="text" name="textoencode"><br>
            <input type="submit">
            <button type="submit" name="phpbutton">Press me</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like my php to know what button was pressed, if encode was pressed, run some code, if decode was pressed, run some other code.

Comment: check I updated my source code! is it what you want?